# how to make width change of a div on hover that takes 2 seconds with tailwind css

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want to add hover effect on my columns on which, the columns would expand in width. I tried the following code with and without tailwind-css.
When hover over any div, the transofrmation happen instantaneously. I want the transition to take at least 2 sec to finish. Tailwind CSS preferred. Thank you.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <script>
    tailwind.config = {
      theme: {
        colors: {
              primary: '#5c6ac4',
              secondary: '#ecc94b',
          },
        extend: { }
      }
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    .custom-css {
        transition: all;
        transition-duration: 2s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
    .custom-css:hover {
        width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex column h-screen">
        <div class="hover:w-full bg-primary transition-all duration-1000">hellow</div>
        <div class="hover:w-full bg-secondary transition-all duration-1000">hellow</div>
        <div class="hover:w-full bg-primary transition-all duration-1000">hellow</div>
        <div class="hover:w-full bg-secondary transition-all duration-1000">hellow</div>
        <div class="hover:w-full bg-primary transition-all duration-1000">hellow</div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex h-screen">
        <div class="custom-css bg-primary ">hellow</div>
        <div class="custom-css bg-secondary ">hellow</div>
        <div class="custom-css bg-primary ">hellow</div>
        <div class="custom-css bg-secondary ">hellow</div>
        <div class="custom-css bg-primary ">hellow</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't use Tailwind, but I have created something similar in vanilla CSS: `.fbl-child { flex: 1 1 0%; transition: flex 150ms ease-in-out } .fbl-child:hover{ flex: 5 5 10% }`  where `5 5` is 2 times the number of FBL child elements. Check out the demo I created some time ago: [Flexbox going berserk](https://renevanderlende.one/discord-stuff/flexbox-mania-revisited.html). Anyway, don't let a framework become a straight-jacket limiting your imagination! Make sure to click the grey nr '1' patch...

Comment: I tried to find resources but I dont't think if transition of changing width will take any custom duration. You can check the style.css here https://play.tailwindcss.com/a87Geb6gFn?file=css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this with just **Tailwind** you need **flex-initial** class and for hover effect **grow** class. But if you want to use it as a custom class, you should  wrap class with **Tailwind** utilities.

```css
@layer utilities {
  .custom-css {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  }
  .custom-css:hover {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="flex column h-screen">
  <div class="flex-initial bg-primary transition-all duration-1000 hover:grow">hellow</div>
  <div class="flex-initial bg-secondary transition-all duration-1000 hover:grow">hellow</div>
  <div class="flex-initial bg-primary transition-all duration-1000 hover:grow">hellow</div>
  <div class="flex-initial bg-secondary transition-all duration-1000 hover:grow">hellow</div>
  <div class="flex-initial bg-primary transition-all duration-1000 hover:grow">hellow</div>
</div>

<div class="flex h-screen">
  <div class="custom-css bg-primary">hellow</div>
  <div class="custom-css bg-secondary">hellow</div>
  <div class="custom-css bg-primary">hellow</div>
  <div class="custom-css bg-secondary">hellow</div>
  <div class="custom-css bg-primary">hellow</div>
</div>
<script>
  tailwind.config = {
    theme: {
      colors: {
        primary: '#5c6ac4',
        secondary: '#ecc94b',
      },
      extend: {},
    },
  };
</script>
```